# Android retrieve and display SMS conversation

Tags: android, listview, sms

I'm trying to build a sms app. I've managed to get all the inbox message and display them in a thread but my approaching is probably wrong. I use a HashMap to store the address and based on it to delete existing message(only display the newest sms)

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
        return;
    adapter.clear();
    do {
        String address = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress);
        if (!hashMap.containsKey(address))
            hashMap.put(address, 0);
        else
            hashMap.put(address, hashMap.get(address) + 1);
        try {
            if (hashMap.containsKey(address)) {
                String str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + ":\n"
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                int count = adapter.getCount();
                while(count>0){
                    String item = adapter.getItem(count);
                    String string = item.substring(0, item.indexOf(':'));
                    if (address.equals(string)) {
                        adapter.remove(item);
                    }
                }
                adapter.add(str);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    smsInboxCursor.close();
}
```

and when I click a thread it will open an intent to display the conversation. The thing is, I have just managed to display only the inbox sms in a thread (no sent sms) like this

[image]

How to retrieve the whole conversation and display it like this

[image]

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how did you solve this? Please provide solution

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code it might help you -

```
  public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

        objSms = new Sms();
        objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
        objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
        objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
        objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
        objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
            objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
        } else {
            objSms.setFolderName("sent");
        }

        lstSms.add(objSms);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
// else {
// throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
// }
c.close();

return lstSms;
 }
```

and model class for sms -

```
public class Sms{
    private String _id;
    private String _address;
    private String _msg;
    private String _readState; //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
    private String _time;
    private String _folderName;

    public String getId(){
      return _id;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
     return _address;
    }
    public String getMsg(){
      return _msg;
    }
    public String getReadState(){
     return _readState;
    }
    public String getTime(){
     return _time;
    }
    public String getFolderName(){
       return _folderName;
    }


    public void setId(String id){
      _id = id;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){
       _address = address;
    }
    public void setMsg(String msg){
     _msg = msg;
    }
    public void setReadState(String readState){
      _readState = readState;
    }
    public void setTime(String time){
      _time = time;
    }
      public void setFolderName(String folderName){
      _folderName = folderName;
      }

   }
```

and dont forget to add permission in your manifest -

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: not what i'm looking for but thanks for sparing your time