# How to Fetch a List of SMS Conversation/Thread? And Display Name Of Contact in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, sms, android-contentresolver

I'm Developing an SMS app, I was able to fetch list of SMS but I want to show them as a Conversation,  How can I achieve It easily since I'm a beginner.

MyChatFragment.java ;

```
    public class AwayFragment extends Fragment {
    public AwayFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyChatFragment, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    int permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    ArrayList<String> smsList;
    smsList = new ArrayList<>();


    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);
    } else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 
    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
     final String TAG = FetchingInboxActivity.class.getSimpleName();

     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        String thread_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString();
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        smsList.add("Number: " + number + "\n" + "Body: " + body + "\n" + "Thread_ID: " + thread_id);
        Log.d(TAG, "showcontacts: ");

        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) 
     view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                () -> {
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        );

    }
    return view;
       }
    }
```

Also, When I'm trying 'content://sms/conversations/' instead of 'content://sms/' I'm showing errors

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column *
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719070/android-retrieve-and-display-sms-conversation

Comment: @UsamaAltaf , Thanks For checking in for me but He has a different case than Mine, He is tryin to fetch messages of specific contact like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShnuX.jpg , But I'm trying to fetch a list of all Peoples with their name and their most recent message

Comment: ContentProvider won't accept * character to get all columns. Pass null instead, and it will work. `null` as `projection` in `query()`, not like string array item. And remeber to move cursor to the first row, by default it's at last row.

Comment: @grabarz121, So when I'm putting null as projection I'm getting error on "column "body" and "address" does not exist"

Comment: Add `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you'll use `cursor.moveToNext()`.

Comment: @grabarz121 I've no idea where do I need to add `cursor.moveToFirst()` . Can you be so kind to tell me that, based on my code above? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, you should move cursor to the first row, before you'll start to read it. Below code works for me in android 10. I'm using this inside if statement, because cursor may be empty, so method will return false.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyChatFragment, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    int permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    ArrayList<String> smsList;
    smsList = new ArrayList<>();


    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);
    } else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    final String TAG = FetchingInboxActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
            String thread_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id"));
            String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            smsList.add("Number: " + number + "\n" + "Body: " + body + "\n" + "Thread_ID: " + thread_id);
            Log.d(TAG, "showcontacts: ");

            final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)
                    view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                    () -> {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            );

        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Be carefur, when you use `toString()` on some data from database, because sometime it may be null, so null to string throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I was able to achieve what I was looking for through your help, But I also want to be able to get the name of person , Can you help me with that as well please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708213/how-to-fetch-and-display-name-and-image-of-conversations-contact