# How to Fetch and Display Name and Image of Conversation's Contact?

Tags: java, android, listview, sms, contacts

I want to achieve something like in screenshot below, So far I am able to display a list of most recent message with message count, But when I'm trying to get the name of person through "address", I'm getting error " **Column address not found**".
**Please help me displaying "contact name with their image".**

[image: What I Want to Achieve]

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyChatFragment, container, false);
    
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
     
    ArrayList<String> smsList;        
    smsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);        
    lv.setAdapter(lva);

    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/");
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
        String message_count = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("msg_count"));
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
        smsList.add("Number: " + number + "\n" + "Message: " + body + "\n" + "Number Of Messages" + 
        message_count );

            }
        }
            return view;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversations uri doesn't contain a column like "address". You can simply look all columns in specific uri via looping `cursor.getColumnName(index)` and print it to logcat. List of columns into specific uri you can also find in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns).

Basicly, Sms ContentProvider doesn't contain informations about contacts, so you need make a second query to `ContactsContract` uri, and find a specific contact via his phone number. Depending of data that you need, there are many uris. You can simply link a phone number from sms with a specific contact using `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`. More detailed information about contacts are in sub-uris of `ContactsContract` ContentProvider. Description about all of them you will find in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract).

Below is simple example. Contact photos isn't stored like photos, but only like a uri to the photo, so you must fetch an image via uri. I didn't test that code too long, so I can't tell you, how it will work e.g. when you have a few contacts with same number.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
            String thread_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id"));
            String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            String name = "";
            String photoUri = "";

            if (number != null) {
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, number);
                String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI};
                Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (contactCursor != null && contactCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            name = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            photoUri = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));
                        } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    contactCursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Note that you need gain `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission to read informations about contacts.